# Solving polynomial roots of any degree only by Vieta's formula

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, mathematica-online

I have already wrote the code that solves it for quadratic formula and I'm curious if this is possible to make that function work with any kind of polynomial(higher degrees) and solving roots only using vietas formula? If, so how can I do this?

```
  solution = Solve[{x1 + x2 == -b/a, x1*x2 == c/a}, {x1, x2}];
  

  roots = {x1, x2} /. solution[[1]];
  

  Print["Rozwiązanie układu równań Viète'a:"];
  Print["x1 = ", x1 /. solution[[1]]];
  Print["x2 = ", x2 /. solution[[1]]];
  
  Print["Pierwiastki wielomianu kwadratowego:"];
  Print["x1 = ", roots[[1]]];
  Print["x2 = ", roots[[2]]];


  polynomial = a*x^2 + b*x + c;
  

  plot = Plot[polynomial, {x, Min[roots] - 1, Max[roots] + 1}, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots]}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Wykres wielomianu kwadratowego"];
  
  (* Wyświetlanie wykresu *)
  Print[plot];
]


QuadraticRootsFromVieta[1, -9, 9]  (* Wielomian kwadratowy x^2 - 9x + 9 *)
```

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but I think this is not always possible. There is no general solution to polynomials which is proven by the Abel-Ruffini theorem.

Comment: This can be done but will give a result in terms of symbolic `Root` objects.